# TR1 regex_replace with wstring in VS2010?

Tags: c++, regex, tr1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <ios>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main () 
{

const wstring wstr(L"<(.|\\n)*?>");
static const wregex wr(wstr);
wstring line (L"<tag>Random text<tag>"); 
wstring line2 (L""); 
wcout << regex_replace<wchar_t>(line,wr,line2) << endl;

}
```

Compiler says:

```
ClCompile:
  html.cpp
c:\users\usr\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\html\html\html.cpp(34): error C2784: std::basic_string<_Elem> std::tr1::regex_replace(const std::basic_string<_Elem> &,const std::tr1::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem> &,std::tr1::regex_constants::match_flag_type): not able to output argument template "const std::tr1::basic_regex<_Elem,wchar_t> &" from "const std::tr1::wregex"
          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\regex(2739): look to typedef "std::tr1::regex_replace"
c:\users\usr\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\html\html\html.cpp(34): error C2784: std::basic_string<_Elem> std::tr1::regex_replace(const std::basic_string<_Elem> &,const std::tr1::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem> &,std::tr1::regex_constants::match_flag_type): not able to output argument template for "const std::tr1::basic_regex<_Elem,wchar_t> &" from "const std::tr1::wregex"
          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\regex(2739): look to  typedef of "std::tr1::regex_replace"
c:\users\usr\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\html\html\html.cpp(34): error C2784: std::basic_string<_Elem> std::tr1::regex_replace(const std::basic_string<_Elem> &,const std::tr1::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem> &,std::tr1::regex_constants::match_flag_type): not able to output argument template for "const std::tr1::basic_regex<_Elem,wchar_t> &" from "const std::tr1::wregex"
          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\regex(2739): look to  typedef "std::tr1::regex_replace"
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is the question?

Comment: sry, I tried to compile it, but It returns errors about template "const std::tr1::basic_regex<_Elem,wchar_t> &" from "const std::tr1::wregex",

Comment: so the question is - how to make it work, with those strings, and display results properly, I've tried the regex_replace(line,wr,line2), without the <wchar_t> - it returns some random info like "00423DA4"

Comment: Can you copy the error? Just saying something general about it won't help anyone help you.

Comment: have added em to the question

Comment: Ok, basically regex_replace<wchar_t> shouldn't compile, because the first template argument is not a the character type, but the traits class. You shouldn't need to specify it. I still don't know why you don't get a replacement when you don't use the wchar_t.

Comment: I'm sorry- this site is in English. I can't read those errors.

Comment: Heh, never knew VC++ can spit out erros in Russian. @DeadMG: It probably means something like "Couldn't decide(?) template argument X from Y". The reason is that the traits argument (RXTraits) was supplied with wchar_t.

Comment: yes, I've translated those to english ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer:

You should use `regex_repalce` this way:

```
wcout << regex_replace(line,wr,line2) << endl;
```

i.e., without the `wchar_t`. The first argument is for the Element Traits class, which you'd only rarely want to modify.

### Edit

I've checked your code with VC++ 2010. Changing the line as I specified allowed the code to compile, and return the result as expected. Can you try it again?

Comment: Yes, I've found out that made some syntactic mistakes with locale in the function, I've used to fill the line1 up, removing <wchar_t> fixed the problem.